# Using Apple with RDP to connect to Windows 2008, @ doesnt work

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, apple

When connecting to Windows 2008 r2 server from Apple mac book air or any other mac I can't get @ to work. 
It works locally on the mac but not on the RDP connection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what a Swedish keyboard layout looks like but on a UK keyboard, @ (at) and " (double quote) get switched.
I've experienced this issue and found using double quote on the keyboard got me an @ (at) symbol.

I commonly get this as I have UK and US macs and control PC's in US, UK & Canada.

Answer (score 1):

The keymapping for the @ sign is different on Mac (Alt-') and PC (AltGr+2) on swedish keyboards and you have to use the PC version for Remote Desktop. Try pressing Ctrl+Alt+2.

Comment: I've tried Ctrl+Alt+2, and all other combinations i can come up with. I just got a tip to try Cord, don't know if it helps the customer is not on site for the moment.

Comment: Is the Win server set to another keymapping? US maybe, so it would be Shift-2 instead. Try starting the On-screen keyboard (not sure if this exists on Win server though) to see where Windows expect it's @ sign.

Comment: If I'm using US keyboard layout it works, shift+2. But when using swedish keyboard layout ctrl + alt + 2 doesn't work. When using On screen keyboard i can press ctrl + alt and then click the @ sign, which appears on "2" on the onscreen keyboard. But I can't press ctrl + alt + 2 on the "real" keyboard.

Comment: This key mapping with any kind of remote connection (VNC/RDC) to anything else than a Mac is a real pain. Another thing to try is Ctrl+Cmd+2 instead of Ctrl+Alt+2.

Comment: Instead of using use@domain.com you can also do domain\user or domain.com\user.

Comment: @ Aaron. Not when sending emails..

Answer (score 0):

I use [CORD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) to connect to our windows boxes.  When I RDP in all I have to hit is Shift+2.  This is using a standard old white Apple keyboard from 3-4 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

On my mac (Danish keyboard) i use Shift+2 works fine every time.